# Javascript regex special character not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
for (;;); {
  "__ar": 1,
  "payload": null,
  "jsmods": {
    "require": [
      ["ServerRedirect", "redirectPageTo", [],
        ["https:\/\/bigzipfiles.facebook.com\/p\/dl\/download\/file.php?r=100028316830939&t=100028316830939&j=11&i=5823694&ext=12121516&hash=AaBVNURld6wrKBcU", true, false]
      ]
    ],
    "define": [
        ["KSConfig", []
        }
```

I try to regex this to be: 
`https://bigzipfiles.facebook.com/p/dl/download/file.php?r=100028316830939&t=100028316830939&j=11&i=5823694&ext=12121516&hash=AaBVNURld6wrKBcU`

I've used

```
var results = $(document).find("pre").html();
var regex1 = new RegExp(/["\w\.\/\;\?\=\-\&\\\\"]/);
var resultsReplace = regex1.exec(results);
console.log(resultsReplace);
```

but it is not working.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Your regular expression matches only a single character. A regular expression to match a URL is only a bit more complex. Have a look at these: [`[javascript] regex extract URL`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+regex+extract+URL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is always URL and the delimiter is always `"` we can use a much simpler regex here, like:

```
str.match(/http[^"]+/)[0]
```

So we looking for a string starting with `http` with any following characters except `"` since the match string never can get one because this is a delimiter.

LMK if cases are wider (not an url, may not start with http, etc.) and I'll adjust regex.

Comment: Thank you so much, I use this `var regex1  = new RegExp(/http[^"]+[\w$]/g);`